Migrate Old ASP.NET Application using EF6 and OWIN to .NET Standard 2.0
We have an old ASP.NET application that uses EF6 and OWIN for authentication. We are currently looking to migrate it to .NET Standard 2.0 => that means we will need to replace EF6 with EF Core so it's compatible with .net standard 2.0. But then the whole OWIN stuff isn't compatible with EF Core as well as .NET Standard 2.0. I'm thinking we would need to replace the whole OWIN stuff with another OAuth server library. Can you give me some recommendations of what to use? Is there another way of migrating them to .NET Standard 2.0?

.NET Standard isn't a platform or runtime, it's a collection of APIs supported by specific runtimes. If you use a supported .NET Framework version (ie 4.6.2 and later) you're already using .NET Standard 2

replace EF6 with EF Core are you confusing .NET Standard with .NET Core? .NET Core is a completely different, cross-platform runtime and platform whose current version is .NET 8. ASP.NET Core and EF Core were completely redesigned. OWIN isn't needed anymore.

If you really want to migrate to ASP.NET Core check the Upgrade from ASP.NET Framework to ASP.NET Core guide

The project in question is a library project that currently targets .NET Framework 4.8. We want to target .NET Standard 2.0 instead.

The only reason to do that is because you want to target both .NET Core and .NET Framework. That means you can't use OWIN at all, besides that's a concern of the application, not the library. You can't use EF Core either though, because any version that targeted .NET Standard 2.0/.NET Framework is already out of support.

The last EF Core version that targeted .NET Standard 2.0 was EF Core 3.1.32 which went out of support in December 2022

@PanagiotisKanavos "The only reason to do that is because you want to target both .NET Core and .NET Framework" - That is correct. We have other projects (which some targets .net framework and some targets .net core) use this library so that's why we want this library to target .net standard 2.0. I agree with you regarding the issues you listed so I'm just trying to see there's anything we can do. Looks like we can't have both lol

Not in 2024. New development moved fully to .NET Core since the release of .NET 6 in 2021. .NET Core 3/EF Core 3 were supported for 3 years until December 2022

I thought everyone was moving to .net 8 now. However, what will matter is if the application was MVC or not? If this is webforms, then that's not supported and a re-write of the software is required, and migration tools will not help you really at all here. So, for a MVC  project, then yes, such a migration will require little changes. The difference between code in .net core, and that of .net framework are VERY minor, and the migration tools can help you a lot. However, again, if this is NOT a MVC project and is webforms, then a application re-write is required.

I would suggest leaving a version of the library in .Net Framework for the legacy applications to continue to use until they can be brought across to .Net Core to utilize a new set of libraries. Note that with .Net Core, software development practice has to adapt to the fact that a framework version is supported for only 1.5-3 years so projects are tasked with keeping up with builds. Not like the supported /w OS for a decade+ like previously.
